# ElasticSearch query that checks for 2 timerange differences

Tags: elasticsearch

Thank you for taking your time and reading this question.

i have an `alert` json object that i store into the ES like so:

```
{
  "generetedOn": "2019-09-16T14:05:45.456Z",
  "receivedOn": "2019-09-16T14:05:45.456Z"
}
```

the data comes from an SQS queue, and sometimes i don't get it in time.

i would like to query for how many documents have a greater lag ( between generatedOn and receivedOn ) then 10 minutes.

i did researched the possibility from the ES documentation, but did not found a way to do it.

Comment: Just substart your fields https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math with a gte 10m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a scripted field to find documents with the difference larger than a specified value:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
        "filter" : {
            "script" : {
                "script" : {
                    "source": "(doc['receivedOn'].value.getMillis()-doc['generetedOn'].value.getMillis() ) > 10*60*1000",
                    "lang": "painless"
                 }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The relevant documentation is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html).

It is also possible to add a scripted field if you want to perform operations on the time difference:

```
GET /_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "diff": {
      "script": {
        "lang":"painless",
        "source":"(doc['receivedOn'].value.getMillis()-doc['generetedOn'].value.getMillis() )==0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```